# Android Studio Artic Fox - Emulator proces terminated

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-arctic-fox

When start avd emulator `The emulator process for AVD pixel2xl has terminated.` get this error.
[image: Crash Record]

I resetted my pc from recovery area and install all of them but still same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved by new patch. Now avd is working.

Comment: Please add the patch version that solved this problem.

Comment: @eglease arctic fox | 2020.3.1 patch 2